# Windows 10 Microsoft Edge Login to hotmail account not working

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have windows 10 64 bit, Microsoft Edge Version 91.0.864.48 (Official build) (64-bit)

After PC starts when I open Edge tab shows just loading and nothing happens, Even If I open new tab same thing happen. Need to wait for like 15 minutes and then it stop loading and then I can access any website.

But this is not only problem, I wanted to login to my hotmail account in Microsoft edge which was working well before, But somehow before a week it logged out and when I am trying to login it give me error  0x80070426 .

I tried to solve it, But till now no success. Edge reset done. Edge update done. But no luck. can someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Logging into Hotmail now really Outlook web) is working fine from Chromium Edge (newest) here. Did you try an alternate browser like Chrome?  Did you restart after resetting Edge?

Comment: Manually delete the entire Chromium Edge profile directory instead of Resetting Edge.

Comment: John thanks for quick reply. I reset Edge, Upgraded to latest version. But no luck. I am not trying to login as web but login to Microsoft edge profile as hotmail account and I am getting this error. It was working and suddenly logged out and now unable to login.

Comment: @Ramhound how I can delete entire edge profile directoy?

Comment: Here is link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUiDJ.png If you want to se error I am getting when I am trying to login as profile

Comment: That looks like an error caused by a proxy.  Navigate to the folder that your Chromium Edge profile is located at

Comment: @Ramhound I am not using any proxy. I used 3 different ISP but still not able to login. Deleted Edge profile, restarted PC and checked, Still same. Cant login. Giving error 0x80070426